# Firebase Using Unique IDs with Flattened Data

Tags: firebase, angularfire, unique-id

I'm trying to flatten the data in my firebase app. The database design has a list of users and a list of projects. The users will own the projects and need to have a list of indexes into which projects they own. The users list is indexed by uid which is unique. With the projects I am using a list of projects with a unique ids. The projects are managed using firebaseArray and created with the $add. I'm trying to use the flattened data model illustrated in the guide in the structuring data section. The problem is that the unique ids generated by the $add have special characters in them and can't be used as the index for the project in the users object. An error is generated when trying to create an object where one of the members has 'special characters' in it.

What is the recommended way to work around this?

Comment: I've added the user id to the project and trying to create a query to get only the projects owned by the current user:

Comment: var projectsRef: Firebase = new Firebase('https://flickering-torch-2606.firebaseio.com/projects');
   
   // create a query for the projects owned by the current user
   var query: any = projectsRef.orderByChild('userId').equalTo(this.userId);

Comment: It can't find the 'userId' in the projectsRef.

Comment: The problem here was the this.userId, not the 'userId'. So this appears to work.

Comment: Can you please include code and data structure examples? See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

For my app I used the orderBy and equalTo with the userId in the projects. This seems to work very well. OrderBy seems like an odd term to use. Its more like a select.

Answer (score 0):

I'm coding a little model layer on top of angularfire, it basically handles (most of ) the pain coming with denormalized data model, you may want to take a look at it [angularfire-resource](https://github.com/itkin/angularfire-resource)

PS : I'm still working on it so it's a bit early to use it in production, but i start to be pretty happy about it and it may give you some ideas